# Connect to SQL Azure DB using OpenRowSet from on-premise SQL Server

Tags: sql, oledb, azure-sql-database

I am trying to connect to SQL Azure database from an on-premise SQL Server using `openrowset`, but it is failing with an error.

My query is

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=sqlazureserver.database.windows.net;Database=dbname;User ID=username;Password=password;Connection Timeout=30;', 'select * from [dbo].[tablename]') AS a;
```

and the error I get:

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. Authentication failed.
>   Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)".

I am able to successfully connect using linked server, but I do not want to go that route as my connection strings will be dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation ,I could see open row set is not supported against SQL Azure database as of now.

[image]

Instead of openrowset,you can use distributed queries to accomplish the same

```
exec ('select * from table') at linkedserver
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I need an alternative solution to dynamically use connection string rather than going Linked Server Route.

Comment: OPENROWSET is now supported on Azure SQL Databases. The one caveat is that if you're using the BULK option the data file needs to be in Azure Blob Storage.